# youtube video insert "onBehalfOfContentOwner" parameter value

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube data API V3 to upload the videos to the youtube.

I am unclear of what should be the value for the paramter "onBehalfOfContentOwner".
Should it be the auth credentials of YouTube CMS user who is managing all the channels..or it should be the Actual channel owner for the youtube .

Comment: have you tried sending them ?

Comment: No I haven't tried yet.I am just going through the documentation of the API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the former.

> "The `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter indicates that the request's
>   authorization credentials identify a **YouTube CMS user** who is acting on
>   behalf of the content owner specified in the parameter value. This
>   parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and manage
>   many different YouTube channels" [[source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)].

But the end of that sections also says:

> "The CMS account that the user authenticates with must be **linked**
>   to the specified YouTube content owner"

which I assume is where the confusion lies. So it needs the auth credentials of YouTube CMS user who's managing the channel, but that account must be linked to the YouTube content owner's account.

Comment: If one is a content owner, like an owner of a channel, what does onBehalfOfContentOwner look like if you want to access a channel?  Is it the human-readable name "cnlohr", the  "YouTube Channel ID" i.e. "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx" or the "YouTube User ID" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx"?  I have a gmail account that is an owner, and another one that is a manager for a channel, and am curious how I can use the API with channel.